# Passing initial query params all the way, in Spring Security OpenID/SAML

Tags: spring-security, openid, saml-2.0

I have an OpenID and SAML integration using Spring Security. I'm using the service initiated flow. I would like to pass any query parameter that is present in the initial URL, all the way to the final redirect, after authentication has taken place.

Example flow would be:

1. User calls `localhost:8080/auth-server/openid?param1=value1`
2. The Auth Server asserts that there is no session and redirects to `localhost:8080/auth-server/oauth2/authorization/registrationId` (this is the default url in `OAuth2AuthorizationRequestRedirectFilter.DEFAULT_AUTHORIZATION_REQUEST_BASE_URI`)
3. The Auth Server then redirects to IdP at `https://idpurl.com/myAppId?params...`
4. The IdP does authentication and ends up redirecting back to `localhost:8080/auth-server/login/oauth2/code/registrationId?params...`
5. The Auth Server finalizes authentication and finally redirects back to the original url `localhost:8080/auth-server/openid` only this time, there is no `param1`.

I'm looking for a way to pass `param1` all the way to the final redirection. Is this supported in Spring Security? Is there a simple way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The out of the box solution is to use the `SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler` which saves the original request and replays it after authentication is successful for the final redirect.